# how to set devexpress lookupedit selected text in gridvidew

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

I have a grid which has two columns and the the first column has a lookupedit. I can fill the grid and the lookupedits but my problem is I dont know how to set the selectedtext according to the database?

[image: This is my grid]

here is how I fill the grid and the lookupedit

```
private void fill_budget_settings(){
        fill_tanim_lookupedit(); 
        gc.DataSource = dataContext.getObjectList("RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS", "*", 0, "", "", 0, 0);
        gv.BestFitColumns();
    }

    private void fill_tanim_lookupedit()
    {
        int cnt = gv.DataRowCount;

        lookUpEditTanim = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();
        lookUpEditTanim.DataSource = dataContext.getObjectList("RN_BUDGET_SETTINGS_VARIABLES", "*", 0, "", "", 0, 0);
        lookUpEditTanim.ValueMember = "VARIABLE";
        lookUpEditTanim.DisplayMember = "VARIABLE";

        gv.Columns[0].ColumnEdit = lookUpEditTanim;
    }
```

when the form is loaded, grid gets filled, lookupedits get filled but lookupedits dont get selected with data required according to the database. how can I do that?

Comment: can you elaborate more about this `lookupedits get filled but lookupedits dont get selected with data required according to the database.` if you want to fill lookup as per the column cell then you can look for assigned editors section in documentation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show editor value according to cell value then specified column to`ValueMember` Property must contain that value which is currently in the cell.

For Example:
In the specified screen shot, Tanm Column have variable id and your want to show variable name in the column then `ValueMember` field should be the ID and `DisplayMember` should be `Variable`.

***Example code snippet:***

```
LookUpEdit ledMyControl;
RepositoryItemLookUpEdit _myRepositoryLookup;
RepositoryItemButtonEdit rbtnEdit;
GridControl grid;
GridView view;
GridView detailView;
GridLevelNode detailNode;
List<Category> categories = new List<Category>();
public GridRepositoryItemTest()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CreateLookupEdit();
    InitializeGrid();
    SetRepositoryLoopEdit();
    InitializeAndAddColumnsToViews();

    InitializeAndBindDataSource();

    detailView.Columns["Category"].ColumnEdit = _myRepositoryLookup;            
}

private void CreateLookupEdit()
{
    ledMyControl = new LookUpEdit();
    ledMyControl.Properties.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("Key"));
    ledMyControl.Properties.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.LookUpColumnInfo("Value"));

    this.Controls.Add(ledMyControl);
    Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    dic.Add("Test", "1");
    dic.Add("Test2", "2");
    dic.Add("Test3", "3");
    dic.Add("Test4", "4");
    dic.Add("Test5", "5");
    dic.Add("Test6", "6");
    dic.Add("Test7", "7");
    dic.Add("Test8", "8");
    dic.Add("Test9", "9");
    dic.Add("Test10", "10"); ledMyControl.Properties.DisplayMember = "Value";
    ledMyControl.Properties.ValueMember = "Key";
    ledMyControl.Properties.DataSource = dic.ToList();

    ledMyControl.Properties.Columns[0].Visible = false;
}

private void InitializeGrid()
{
    grid = new GridControl();
    view = new GridView(grid);
    detailView = new GridView(grid);
    detailNode = grid.LevelTree.Nodes.Add("Books", detailView);
    grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    this.Controls.Add(grid);
    detailView.ValidateRow += new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ValidateRowEventHandler(detailView_ValidateRow);

}

void detailView_ValidateRow(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ValidateRowEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("It's working");
}        

private void InitializeAndAddColumnsToViews()
{
    if (view != null && detailView != null)
    {
        view.Columns.AddField("CategoryID").VisibleIndex = 0;
        detailView.Columns.AddField("ID").VisibleIndex = 0;
        detailView.Columns.AddField("Name").VisibleIndex = 1;
        detailView.Columns.AddField("Category").VisibleIndex = 2;                    
    }
}

private void InitializeAndBindDataSource()
{
    CreateCategories();
    BindingList<BookDetail> bookDetails = new BindingList<BookDetail>();

    BookDetail bookDetail = null;
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        bookDetail = new BookDetail { CategoryID = categories[j].ID };
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            bookDetail.Books.Add(new Book
            {
                ID = 1,
                Name = "Book - " + (i + 1),
                Category = categories[j].ID
            });
        }
        bookDetails.Add(bookDetail);
    }
    grid.DataSource = bookDetails;
}

private void CreateCategories()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        categories.Add(new Category
        {
            ID = i,
            Name = "Category - " + i
        });
    }
}

private void SetRepositoryLoopEdit()
{
    //rbtnEdit.Click += new EventHandler(rbtnEdit_Click);
    //rbtnEdit.ButtonClick += new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventHandler(rbtnEdit_ButtonClick);
    _myRepositoryLookup = new RepositoryItemLookUpEdit();
    _myRepositoryLookup.Name = "redCategories";
    _myRepositoryLookup.DataSource = categories;
    _myRepositoryLookup.ValueMember = "ID";
    _myRepositoryLookup.DisplayMember = "Name";
    grid.RepositoryItems.Add(_myRepositoryLookup);         
    _myRepositoryLookup.EditValueChanged += new EventHandler(_myRepositoryLookup_EditValueChanged);               

}

void rbtnEdit_ButtonClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

void rbtnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

void _myRepositoryLookup_EditValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your code here
}
```

If you are not doing as above and want to get value according to column cell. then you must take the [Inplace Editors Overview](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument745) and check the `See Also` section in the page and there you will get one [**Assigning Editors to Individual Cells**](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument747).

***Example:***

```
using DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid;

private void gridView1_CustomRowCellEdit(object sender, CustomRowCellEditEventArgs e) {
   if (e.Column.FieldName == "FieldName") return;
   GridView gv = sender as GridView;
   string fieldName = gv.GetRowCellValue(e.RowHandle, gv.Columns["FieldName"]).ToString();
   switch (fieldName) {
      case "Population":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemSpinEdit1;
         break;
      case "Country":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemComboBox1;
         break;
      case "Capital":
         e.RepositoryItem = repositoryItemCheckEdit1;
         break;
   }           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert form load inside blok below text

```
lookUpEditTanim.EditValue = Yours lookUpEdit ID columns items name, which you are binding from the DB;
```

Answer (score 0):

set with help of value

```
lookUpEditTanim.EditValue ="2"
```

set with help of text

```
lookUpEditTanim.EditValue=lookUpEditTanim.Properties.GetKeyValueByDisplayText("text_of_value_2");
```